# How to link button and delete first element of a list with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble deleting the first element in a list when clicking on a button. I know that there is a solution regarding this problem. However, I just could figure it out
Is it something like this. The zap button has a class id = "zap"

```js
$(".zap").click(function(){
    $("li").first().remove();
});
```

```html
<button id="zap">Zap</button>
<ol>
  <li>First item</li>
  <li>Second item</li>
  <li>Third item</li>
  <li>Fourth item</li>
  <li>Fifth item</li>
  <li>Sixth item</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Does the button have a class or id? Also, does the list have a class or id? It would be helpful to know. If you can, please provide the HTML.

Comment: the button have id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button has an id, so you need to bind the event to the id. Also, the JQuery should be wrapped in document.ready function:

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){
   $("#zap").on("click", function(){
     $("li").first().remove();
   });
});
```

```html
<button id="zap">Zap</button>
<ol>
  <li>First item</li>
  <li>Second item</li>
  <li>Third item</li>
  <li>Fourth item</li>
  <li>Fifth item</li>
  <li>Sixth item</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I cannot tell without seeing the HTML. It should work, if it doesn't there is something else going on.

Comment: wait how do i post html

Comment: Same way you posted your JQuery.

Comment: so with the html going on do i need to use the parent inheritance to make it work?

Comment: Do you have JQuery set up? And is your JQuery code wrapped in document.ready function? Those are the only two things that come to my mind, because it's working when I try it myself.

Comment: i have it linked to the html with the jQuery library as well as the javascript.

Comment: never mind thank you so much I was just being dumb I forget to add it under the document .ready. Thank you again .

Answer (score 0):

Remove first element different types.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function(){

    //method 1
   jQuery("#zap").on("click", function(){
        jQuery("li:eq(0)").remove();
   });

   //method 2
   jQuery("#zap").on("click", function(){
        jQuery("li:first").remove();
   });

   //method 3
   jQuery("#zap").on("click", function(){
        jQuery("li").first().remove();
   });
  //Method 4 
   jQuery("#zap").on("click", function(){
      jQuery("li:first-of-type").remove();
   });  

});
```